# Find out which browsers are installed?

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to find out which browsers are installed on the Android Smartphone and their package names.

Why do I need it?

Well basically, my App reacts on certain URLs, i.e. http://bit.ly, so when the click such an he will get an choice in which App to open it. So far everything is working as intended.

If the user sets up this app as default for this kind of links, it will always open in this one without further asking the user. So far so good too. But by doing this, he will be completely unable to open this links in his browser.

So I need a way to send this intent directly to the browser, but to do so I have to know which app the user has set to be default for http/https scheme for example (as user can change it if there is more than 1 browser installed).

Sending the intend with

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
```

should't be a problem I think. The problem is, I can't send a standard intent für URLs, because my App would catch it again if set as default by the user.

Comment: Why are you trying to set up to send to a default browser? Just send the link as an intent and let the phone decide what browser is set as default.

Comment: Because if I do send it as normal Intent, my App would catch it again (if set as default). In this case, it's not the desired result. 

Let's say you have an App which catches http://www.flickr.com/photos/ urls and they open in your App. But now you want to give the user a chance to open it in a browser too. If you send a normal intent, your app would open it up again. So you need to send it to a specific browser so your app WON'T catch it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should't be a problem I think

Hardwiring in the package and class names of code that is not yours is ***always*** a problem.

> So I need a way to send this intent directly to the browser, but to do so I have to know which app the user
>   has set to be default for http/https scheme for example (as user can change it if there is more than 1
>   browser installed).

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivityOptions()` to filter your activity out and get a list of other activities that the user can choose from.